# Filling SharePoint Calendar List With Bulk Data(About 3000 Entries)

Tags: list, excel, sharepoint-calendar

I want to fill about 3000 entries in a SharePoint calendar List for testing purpose. I have tried using  [this](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/SharePoint-How-to-Add-Events-into-a-Calendar-Using-Microsoft-Excel-and-Access.aspx) link but i have some lookup columns and person/group fields which do not appear in the excel sheet? Is there any other way of adding bulk items in a calender list.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell to the rescue! You can import your data using PowerShell rather easy, including user accounts and lookups. Check out

Loading SharePoint lists from Excel using PowerShell
http://davidlozzi.com/2012/02/29/loading-sharepoint-lists-from-excel/

Using PowerShell to play with SharePoint Items
http://davidlozzi.com/2012/02/14/playing-with-sharepoint-data-in-powershell/

Using PowerShell to access SharePoint Sites, Users, and Groups
http://davidlozzi.com/2012/03/07/using-powershell-to-access-sharepoint-sites/